# Code that writes itself when executed

Tags: self, instructions, quine

Is there any computer program that can display on console or any other medium the instructions that composed it? Does any computer language have capabilities for this? Is it possible?

Comment: It's very simple for a short script to open its own source file and print it to the console, is this what you mean?

Comment: such programs are called quines. Google the term.

Comment: @SamuelLittley Yes i guess so.

Comment: You can find plenty [on the code golf site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short python example:

Assuming that the source code is in the file `/path/to/file.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open('/path/to/file.py') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

This is a very contrived example, but it illustrates the point.

**EDIT**

By the definition of a quine this is technically cheating as it takes input by reading its own source file

Comment: `_='_=%r;print(_%%_)';print(_%_)` (followed by a newline) is an actual quine that outputs `_='_=%r;print(_%%_)';print(_%_)` (followed by a newline) when run. It does depend on `.py` being bound to python rather than the crashbang though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly read the file in your program to achieve this. If you run the following command in Python it would also work:

```
def write_itself():
    code = 'def write_itself():\n\t code = {!r}\n\t print(code.format(code)) \nwrite_itself()'
    print(code.format(code))
write_itself()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its own source code?
Write a **quine**, techniques for which differ by language:

- Cem Birler's answer on this question with a Python quine
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine

Or as Samuel shows, a program that opens its own source file via the filesystem.

---

Or output the machine instructions it compiles to?
For that, you can write a program that runs a disassembler on itself, like Linux `objdump -drWC` (optionally with `-Mintel` for x86).  e.g. on Linux, `argv[0]` is normally the command name.  It might or might not be a full path, but that's enough for a toy program.

```
#include <spawn.h>

int main(){
        posix_spawn(NULL, "/usr/bin/objdump", NULL, NULL, (char*[]){"objdump", "-drwC", "/proc/self/exe", NULL}, NULL);
     // execution continues here; unlike execve we didn't replace our own process
     // optional: waitpid(child_pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
}
```

I used `posix_spawn` just to see how it works (and *if* it works with NULL for `envp` like Linux `execve` allows, and most of the other optional things including the child_pid).  The `system(3)` library function or `fork`+`exec*` system calls can do the equivalent.

(Linux `/proc/self/exe` is always the current process's executable.  But that would get `objdump` to disassemble itself, not your program.  `/dev/fd/0` after your program redirects stdin from `/proc/self/exe` would work.)